# Docusign API: Template roles not being merged

Tags: docusignapi

When creating an envelope using a template, the recipient data is not merging with the role defined in the template despite having the same role name. Instead, the data defined in the request is sent in addition to the default template role. Here is the request being sent:

```
{  
       "emailSubject":"Example Email",
       "status":"created",
       "templateId":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
       "templateRoles":[  
          {  
             "email":"john.doe@gmail.com",
             "name":"John Doe",
             "roleName":"role_01"
          }
       ]
}
```

When I examine the draft saved in the app demo, there are now 2 recipients on the envelope: John Doe and the placeholder in the template. Despite having the same role name, John Doe does not inherit any of the template tabs for 'role_01'.

This request was made using Docusign's PHP SDK.

EDIT:

Here is the request logged in DocuSign:

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net:7802/restapi/v2/accounts/[omitted]/envelopes

TraceToken: 273fe6c7-ac95-46b5-8c04-27fb91b6b9a4
Timestamp: 2018-04-04T16:43:42.6317470Z

Content-Length: 221
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
User-Agent: Swagger-Codegen/2.0.1/php
X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"56eeb1f9-b9ae-40b1-94f7-5fff2ed2a67f","Password":"[omitted]","IntegratorKey":"[omitted]"}
X-DocuSign-SDK: PHP
X-SecurityProtocol-Version: TLSv1.2
X-SecurityProtocol-CipherSuite: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
x-forwarded-for: 70.234.88.244

{"emailSubject":"Please Sign","status":"created","templateId":"a0e38e1b-a8af-4ce9-9398-cc1bb4bbb5d3","templateRoles":[{"email":"john.doe@gmail.com","name":"John Doe","roleName":"role_01"}]}
201 Created
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-DocuSign-TraceToken: 273fe6c7-ac95-46b5-8c04-27fb91b6b9a4

{
  "envelopeId": "e6a04bb7-f73f-4f22-84a5-b3d4e8ce1fea",
  "uri": "/envelopes/e6a04bb7-f73f-4f22-84a5-b3d4e8ce1fea",
  "statusDateTime": "2018-04-04T16:43:42.2270000Z",
  "status": "created"
}
```

Comment: Can you please check if there is roleName mismatch between DS Server template and your code. Both should exactly match. If its same, can you please attach your template if possible, and I will try it on my account. Also check what SDK code is sending to DS, you can see logs using https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have compared the role names multiple times to make sure they are exactly the same. I also tried multiple role names. Here is what displays after creating the draft. https://imgur.com/a/Hoxhx You can see that instead of merging the new data into the role, it just creates an additional recipient despite having the same role name.

Comment: Can you share the logs which you can capture per above link

Comment: See edit to original post for the logged request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be having `Name` and `Email` already present in the template. I think you have `FirstName LastName`, `example@email.com` in the template name, email respectively. `Delete` these values in the template, template should only have roleName.